Php 8 session id resets on page refresh (or when I change page)
Every time I change page or refresh the page I lose all my sessions variables, after while I figured out it was caused by the session id that changes everytime (I think it is because of this). Something strange, is that for a day the session id stopped changing and it worked and then again, it doesn't work anymore.
Here is my config session file :
<?php

ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);
ini_set("session.use_strict_mode", 1);

session_set_cookie_params([
    "lifetime" => 1800,
    "domain" => "localhost",
    "path" => "/", // session marche partout
    "secure" => true, // marche seulement avec une connexion https
    "httponly" => true, // l'utilisateur ne puisse pas changer les cookies avec un script de hack
]);

session_start();


@1GuizmoU please check the session by putting into if else its ... and try to echo the msg.

Can you put  session_start(); on the top ..

When the server sends the session cookie to the client, check if the client can read it properly and check whether the client sends the same cookie back to the server unaltered. Since you are using localhost AND secure here make sure you've properly configured HTTPS in your localhost server

@RïshïKêshKümar Thanks for your response, I did put session_start(); at the top and it seems to work :)

putting session_start at the top will ignore session_set_cookie_params so it's likely a configuration issue in those settings

@GuizmoU okay so its workz ?
